# Regex match everything except a given substring

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I know variations of this question have been asked in the past, but none of the examples I've tried out have been effective. So, one more time, how can I match all but a given substring with regex?

For example, select everything but `stupid` from this Einstein quote:

```
Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.
```

I've had some success capturing everything up to `stupid` using `((?!stupid).)*`, but no luck with getting all of it. I've been testing with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: If you are trying to drop `stupid` then it will split string into two parts. Thus giving you two separate strings or you might want to join these two strings. I don't see why you want to do that ? So specifying clearly the format of output and what you intend to do will be helpful.

Comment: Not trying to drop `stupid`, but drop everything else by way of a `Select-String -replace ""` command in Powershell (at the moment).

Comment: How about, instead of a vague theoretical question, you provide sample input, the code that is your attempt to solve the problem, the result of running that ode (whether it's an error or an incorrect/unexpected result), and an example of the result you're looking for?  A pattern match using a regular expression depends on the RE engine you're using.

Comment: I'd like for this to work anywhere. It shouldn't matter the string being used or the app/language. If it matches on regex101.com or regexr.com, chances are it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would capture strings besides the `stupid`
like this:

```
^(.*)stupid(.*)$
```

and print( or do sth else; ) two times with `\1 , \2` or `$1 , $2`...

---

anyway, is there any method that can capture non-connected strings at once?

Comment: What if there are two or more occurrences of the excluded word?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that looks different problem to this (IMO) I would delete all occurences of excluded words in advance and use it

Comment: Could you give a working example to test out regex101.com? Not too familiar with using backreferences.

Comment: @Mica [here](https://regex101.com/r/pP6uR2/2) , I think you should choose specific language to play with these... isn't it lack of features with 'pure regex' ??